# Laravel 6.0 Composer dependency upgrade error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-upgrade, laravel-6

I changed in my composer "laravel/framework": "^6.0". I ran the command `composer update` and I get an error and it's not updated.

My current version is 5.8.2 Thanks for the help!

Image with error:

https://imge.to/i/vUDUvy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in the message in your screenshot, it looks like Laravel Omnipay may not yet be ready for laravel 6.0.  According to the [git page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-omnipay), it may not have been updated recently.

You may wish to check with the developer, Barryvdh, to see if there will be an upgrade coming soon.

Comment: humm do you know any other alternative?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use the package - I just was trying to answer the question, as I've had similar issues updating other packages.  Sometimes devs don't update at all and I have had to change to other packages, sometimes i've had to keep Laravel back due to breaking changes.  Barryvdh, though is an outstanding dev - if this is his package, and something he is supporting, I would bet he will update it soon.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the error more closely, it looks like there is another package out there for Omnipay, and that you are using that one.  This one looks even older.  I didn't look too deeply, but it looks like it may require Larvel 5.  Maybe take a look at the other one, that I linked to in the answer.  Maybe that one is compatible.